# How does input value work?

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri, html-input

There is a input tag in a webpage. When I inspect it:

```
<input type="text" onmouseover="this.select();" readonly="" value="<embed src=&quot;https://imgcache.qq.com/tencentvideo_v1/playerv3/TPout.swf?max_age=86400&amp;v=20161117&amp;vid=d0380tpvuqx&amp;auto=0&quot; allowFullScreen=&quot;true&quot; quality=&quot;high&quot; width=&quot;480&quot; height=&quot;400&quot; align=&quot;middle&quot; allowScriptAccess=&quot;always&quot; type=&quot;application/x-shockwave-flash&quot;></embed>">
```

But when I view its' page source:

```
<input type="text" onmouseover="this.select();" readonly r-attr="{value:shareHtml}">
```

How does it work? And how can I get the input value by `nokogiri` since the parsed result looks like this:

```
#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fcc71309c60 name="input" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fcc71309be8 name="type" value="text">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fcc71309bd4 name="onmouseover" value="this.select();">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fcc71309bc0 name="readonly" value="readonly">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fcc71309bac name="r-attr" value="{value:shareHtml}">]>
```

Comment: It looks like there is javascript that updates the `value` basing on `r-attr` attribute’s value. There is no way to get the resulting value with `Nokogiri`.

Comment: You can't get it. You're inspecting the DOM of the page as the browser knows it. Nokogiri isn't a browser, it's a parser, which is just one part of what a browser does. All Nokogiri knows is what the HTML looks like when it's initially retrieved, just as the browser does when it first retrieves the HTML. But then the browser runs all the scripts embedded in the page, and processes the CSS, then it displays the resulting modified page to you. What you see when you inspect the page reflects the page currently being displayed, not what was originally received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the value with Nokogiri alone, however you can get it if you use a tool that is loading the javascript before you get the html. One tool like this would be Selenium, which is using the browser to load the page first.

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

You need to wait for some change on the page, to know that the js has finished.
You can do that by waiting for some element with a certain css tag has appeared:

```
driver.find_element(:css, '#some-id')
```

Or just wait a set anount of time:

```
sleep(2)
```

After the javascript have changed the content of the page, you get the new html source:

```
html_source = driver.page_source
driver.quit
```

Then you can use Nokogiri to parse the html:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html_source)
doc.at('input')['value']
```